# How can I access core/paragraph textColor in a block template

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to set the default textColor of an Innerblocks => paragraph in my Gutenberg block plugin.

The problem seems to be that placeholder is an attribute but textColor is passed as a prop https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/edit.js

Wondering if anyone has figured out how to set this. Or if it is not possible.

The documentation does not seem to cover this https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-templates/

```js
<InnerBlocks
  template={[
    ["core/paragraph", { placeholder: "Enter side content...", textColor: '#EF4A23' }]
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: Try `customTextColor` instead, I think it should work.

Comment: I'm late to the party but have you figured it out?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Same problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As of the end 2020**, I have found that the best way to find attributes related to a core block is to inspect it with the [react developer tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html#installation).

Under the components tab, search for `[BLOCK_NAME]Edit` to find the editing component, where `[BLOCK_NAME]` is something like "Paragraph", "Heading" or "Button".

Then on the right side in the inspector you can see the related attributes.

**To answer the original question**, at the current moment, the attribute is `textColor`.

```
const TEMPLATE = [
    [
        'core/paragraph',
        {
            textColor: '[YOUR-COLOR-SLUG]',
        },
    ]
]
```

In my case entering an hexadecimal value doesn't seem to work. But this might be because I have disabled the custom color selector globally.

Comment: Super helpful!  I wasn't having any luck passing HEX values but the slug of a custom color added to the `editor-color-palette` did work.  Great tip!